# How to include FirstOrDefault() in ToList()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to get only one file for each recipe.

```
var UploadedFiles = (from rec in db.Recipes
                     join files in db.Files on rec.Id equals files.RecipeId
                     select new
                     {
                         files.Id,
                         files.Path,
                         files.RecipeId,
                         rec.Name,
                         rec.Description,
                         rec.Category,
                         rec.CookTime
                     }).ToList();
return new JsonResult { Data = UploadedFiles, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Comment: @FCin I need it to return as a list since I have many recipes

Comment: @RahulSingh that will return just first item from all of the result-set

Comment: @RahulSingh `var UploadedFiles = (from rec in db.Recipes
                                 join files in db.Files on rec.Id equals files.RecipeId
                                 select new { files.Id, files.Path, files.RecipeId, rec.Name, rec.Description, rec.Category, rec.CookTime }).FirstOrDefault();
            return new JsonResult { Data = UploadedFiles, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };` only returns 1 record.

Comment: What I don't understand is what you want to get if files is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use group join instead of regular join, I presume it is also more efficient than the previous answer (with the let), although I am not fully aware of EF query optimizations in this case

```
var UploadedFiles = (from rec in db.Recipes
                 join files in db.Files on rec.Id equals files.RecipeId into g
                 let firstFile = g.FirstOrDefault()
                 select new
                 {
                     firstFile.Id,
                     firstFile.Path,
                     firstFile.RecipeId,
                     rec.Name,
                     rec.Description,
                     rec.Category,
                     rec.CookTime
                 }).ToList();
```

### Update

since I don't use EF, I can't really confirm whether or not it handles nulls but I have been informed it doesn't you would have to remove nulls.

```
var UploadedFiles = (from rec in db.Recipes
                 join files in db.Files on rec.Id equals files.RecipeId into g
                 let firstFile = g.FirstOrDefault()
                 where firstFile != null
                 select new
                 {
                     firstFile.Id,
                     firstFile.Path,
                     firstFile.RecipeId,
                     rec.Name,
                     rec.Description,
                     rec.Category,
                     rec.CookTime
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: I suspect that will throw an exception if there are no files

Comment: I too suspect that, however since I do not use EF, and the guy from the other answer said linq handles nulls, I am listening to him.
EF converts the linq to SQL, so I find it believable.

Comment: I would use ?. notation to handle nulls

Comment: @gilmishal Regarding your last comment. Unfortunately `?.` operator currently is not supported in expression trees (C# compiler error).

Comment: Weird, it works for me in c# 7.2 with linq to objects

Comment: @gilmishal LINQ To Objects does not use expression trees. Try with `from x in someList.AsQueryable() select x?.SomeProp`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, however, I can't confirm whether or not EF actually handles null checks with the expression trees, I would expect it to handle it.

Comment: @gilmishal The 1st query works if there are no null files, the second throws this exception `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code`

Comment: @gilmishal Please update your answer and add `where firstFile != null` after the `let`  without the  `?? new File()` so I can mark it as answer thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following...

```
var UploadedFiles = (from rec in db.Recipes
                 from files in db.Files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.RecipeId == rec.Id)
                 select new
                 {
                     files.Id,
                     files.Path,
                     files.RecipeId,
                     rec.Name,
                     rec.Description,
                     rec.Category,
                     rec.CookTime
                 }).ToList();
return new JsonResult { Data = UploadedFiles, JsonRequestBehavior = 
JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

Comment: Just make sure there are null checks

Comment: null will automatically handled by Linq.

Comment: This does not compile - `from` requires sequence. Use `let files = ...` instead.

Comment: It doesn't get handled by linq to objects, but interesting to know that linq to entities handles it, and Ivan is right

Comment: @IvanStoev, its compiling and also working as expected. I have tested it at my end.

Comment: @Nitesh No offense here, just telling you how to correct your code. There is no way `from files in db.Files.FirstOrDefault(...)` to compile because `FirstOrDefault` returns *single* object while `from x in y` construct requires `y` to be enumerable (sequence).

Comment: @Nitesh It returned this error `An expression of type 'File' is not allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 'DBSet<Recipe>'.Type inference failed in the call to 'SelectMany'`